# Why is the method in one class of a project not recognizing another class's method?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Java program with Eclipse that roughly simulates a small town with several people or characters and their interactions.

I added a class - *character* - that has a method - *meet(character)*. However, when I try to call *meet(character)* with a character object in another class - *location* - in the same package and project in Eclipse it results in the error: The method meet(character) is undefined for the type character.

The first chunk of code I'm including is my *location* class. It includes only the *add* method.

The second chunk of code is my *character* class, including only the *meet(character)* and *getID()* methods

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class location<character> implements List<character> {

private String name;
private ArrayList<character> occupants;
private boolean professional;
private int cost;
private character owner;
private int hours;

public location(character o,  boolean prof, String n, int c, int h)
{
    name = n;
    professional = prof;
    cost = c;
    owner = o;
    hours = h;

}
//Methods other than add(character c) have been excluded
public boolean add(character c)
{
    for(character a:occupants)
    {
        //This if statement is the part with errors. 
        //Error message: The method meet(character) is undefined for the type character
        if(c.meet(a))
        {
            a.meet(c);
        }
    }
    return occupants.add(c);
}
}
```

Second chunk of code, the *character* class with the *meet(character)* method

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class character
{
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private job j;
    private static int count;
    private int id;
    private String gender;
    private ArrayList<Integer> relations = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public character(String n, String l, String g)
    {
        firstname = n;
        lastname = l;
        gender = g;
        id = count;
        count = count + 1;
    }

    //Method meet, not being recognized by class location.
    //Both files are in the same package in an Eclipse project.

    public boolean meet(character person)
    {
        relations.ensureCapacity(person.getID());
        if(!(relations.get(person.getID()) > 0 && relations.get(person.getID()) <= 100))
        {
            relations.add(person.getID(), new Integer(50));
            if(relations.get(person.getID()).intValue() == 50)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you need me to provide more of my code just ask. I've looked for a problem like mine but I haven't found a way to word it that returns relevant results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
class location<character> implements List<character>
               ^--here--^
```

In this case, the name of your generic is `character`, thus generating issues in your code. You need to get rid of that generic definition and use this:

```
class location implements List<character>
```

In fact, you don't even need your `location` class to implement `List<character>`, just use it as a wrapper of a `List<character>`:

```
public class location<character> {

    private List<character> occupants;
    //...

}
```

Last but not least, I highly recommend you to follow the [Naming Conventions for Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). This is, rename the class `location` per `Location` and `character` by `Char` or `NPC` or something similar.